# pandas data frame splitting by column values using Parallel Processing

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a really large pandas dataframe and I am trying split it into multiple ones by stock names and save them to csv.

```
 stock     date     time   spread  time_diff 
  VOD      01-01    9:05    0.01     0:07     
  VOD      01-01    9:12    0.03     0:52     
  VOD      01-01   10:04    0.02     0:11
  VOD      01-01   10:15    0.01     0:10     
  BAT      01-01   10:25    0.03     0:39  
  BAT      01-01   11:04    0.02    22:00 
  BAT      01-02    9:04    0.02     0:05
  BAT      01-01   10:15    0.01     0:10     
  BOA      01-01   10:25    0.03     0:39  
  BOA      01-01   11:04    0.02    22:00 
  BOA      01-02    9:04    0.02     0:05
```

I know how to do this in. conventional way

```
def split_save(df):
    ids = df['stock'].unique()
    for id in ids:
        df = df[df['stock']==id]
        df.to_csv(f'{my_path}/{id}.csv')
```

However, since I got a really large dataframe and thousands of stocks, I want to multiprocessing for acceleration.

Any thought ?  (I might also try pyspark later.)

Thank you !

Comment: Try to use `df.groupby("stock")` and see if it isn't faster.

Comment: Thanks. @AndrejKesely   I also need to name the output file by the stock ID. Can I manage to do that using groupby ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that `groupby` is what's holding you back, but for writing we could speed things up by `multithreading` like this:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# Number of cores/threads your CPU has/that you want to use.
workers = 4 

def save_group(grouped):
    name, group = grouped
    group.to_csv(f'{name}.csv')

with ThreadPoolExecutor(workers) as pool:
    processed = pool.map(save_group, df.groupby('stock'))
```

Comment: Haha, same answer, different color ;) Actually I like yours better

Comment: Thanks @BeRT2me  It works. Now I need to do the similar process on Pyspark . Could you help me ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359870/pyspark-dataframe-splitting-and-saving-by-column-values-by-using-parallel-proces

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Being I/O involved I don't expect the selection of the dataframe to be the main blocking point.

So far, I can provide you two solutions to speed it up:

**Threading:** Just launch each stock in a different thread or in a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)

```
def dump_csv(df, ticker):
    df.groupby(ticker).to_csv(f'{my_path}/{ticker}.csv')

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(df, ticker):ticker for ticker in df['stock'].unique()}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        print(f"Dumped ticker {futures[future]}")
```

(code not tested, adapted from the example)

**Working in a ZIP file**: For storing many many files, zip archives is a very good option, but it should be supported by the "reader".

For the sake of completeness:

```
with ZipFile('stocks.zip', 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    ids = df['stock'].unique()
    for id in ids:
        zf.writestr(f'{id}.csv', df.groupby(ticker).to_csv())
```

Comment: Thanks @Zaero Divide   
It works. Now I need to do the similar process on Pyspark . Could you help me ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359870/pyspark-dataframe-splitting-and-saving-by-column-values-by-using-parallel-proces

Thanks