# create and save dataframes from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

An extract from my df (35k rows in total):

```
stop_id                      time
7909    2022-04-06T03:47:00+03:00
7909    2022-04-06T04:07:00+03:00
1009413 2022-04-06T04:10:00+03:00
1002246 2022-04-06T04:19:00+03:00
1009896 2022-04-06T04:20:00+03:00
```

I want to create separate dataframes for every unique `stop_id` column, in each dataframe I need to have `stop_id` (which is constant for every row), `time` field with only unique values and `number` column which aggregates the rows with the same `time` value. So, assuming there are 50 unique `stop_id` values, I want to get 50 separate csv files containing all the data above. How can I do this?

hope the explanation doesn't seem messy

I have this line of code

```
df.groupby(['time']).agg({'time':'size','stop_id': ", ".join})
```

but it doesn't keep the value of `stop_id`

expected output:
csv1

```
stop_id   time                      number   
7909      2022-04-06T03:47:00+03:00 1
7909      2022-04-06T04:07:00+03:00 1
7909      2022-04-06T05:00:00+03:00 2
...
```

csv2

```
stop_id      time                      number   
1009413      2022-04-06T04:10:00+03:00 1
1009413      2022-04-06T04:19:00+03:00 3
1009413      2022-04-06T04:30:00+03:00 5
...
```

Comment: so, each csv should have only 1 line? Can you provide the expected text of the csv for stop_id 7909?

Comment: added in the question. each csv should have rows with unique values of `time` which have a unique and only one for this csv value of `stop_id`, and the column containing aggregation of the `time` appearances.

Comment: I guess you should `groupby` the `stop_id` first?

Comment: BTW, your example cannot be reproduced, as the data is missing, all data has a number=1 ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72333215/pandas-data-frame-splitting-by-column-values-using-parallel-processing/72333777#72333777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `group_by` on both `stop_id` and `time` and use the `size()` aggregation to get what will be the `number` column in each Data Frame. After that, you can filter all the unique `stop_id` and iterate over each group to construct the single Data Frame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {"stop_id": [...], "time": [...]} # Your Data

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data) # Create the DataFrame from the data

# The GroupBy DataFrame has the MultiIndex with the form (stop_id, time)
g = df.groupby(['stop_id', 'time']).size()

# Set of stop_ids, you can also use df.stop_id.unique()
stops = { i[0] for i in g.index }

# Iterate over every unique stop_id
for stop in stops:
    # Filter only the groups with the right stop_id
    times = filter(lambda x: x[0] == stop, g.index)
    
    # Prepare new DataFrame
    data = { "stop_id": [], "time": [], "number": []}
    
    # Iterate over each unique time for the specific stop_id
    for time in times:
        data["stop_id"].append(stop) # add the stop_id
        data["time"].append(time[1]) # add the current time
        data["number"].append(g[(stop, time[1])]) # add its count

    # Save the DataFrame as a CSV
    pd.DataFrame(data=data).to_csv(f"{stop}.csv", index=False)
```

**Edit to address comment**

If I understood correctly, instead of number you now want to have a list of elements that in the previous script are the count. This is possible thanks to the `apply()` method, used in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {"stop_id": [...], "route_name": [...], "time": [...]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# The GroupBy DataFrame has the tuple (stop_id, time) as Indexes
# Apply the list() function over the values of "route_name" in the group
g = df.groupby(['stop_id', 'time'])["route_name"].apply(list)
print(g)

# Set of stop_ids
stops = { i[0] for i in g.index }
print(g)
for stop in stops:
    times = filter(lambda x: x[0] == stop, g.index)
    data = { "stop_id": [], "time": [], "route_names": []}
    for time in times:
        data["stop_id"].append(stop)
        data["time"].append(time[1])
        data["route_names"].append(g[(stop, time[1])])
    pd.DataFrame(data=data).to_csv(f"{stop}.csv", index=False)
```

Pay attention to the fact that in this way, if you read one of the produced CSV into a Pandas Data Frame, you have to convert the field `route_names` from a String to a List. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742976/how-to-read-a-column-of-csv-as-dtype-list-using-pandas) you can find some approaches to perform this operation.

Comment: wow this is exactly what I need! thank you! how should I change the code so that it also appends other columns' values? I have a column ```route_name``` which has different values for each unique ```stop_id```, and I want to list these ```route_name``` values per each ```time``` row. context: a bus arrives at ```stop_id``` at a certain time, but there can be several buses arriving at the same time, so I want to know which ```route_name``` arrived

Comment: @Semyon edited the answer in order to address the specific use. As stated in the answer, I would rather do the row selection for the specific couple of (`stop_id`, `route_name`) and then get the values of the `route_name` column, since the conversion from the CSV is not trivial