# Pyspark dataframe splitting and saving by column values by using Parallel Processing

Tags: python, pyspark, multiprocessing

I have a really large pyspark dataframe and I am trying split it into multiple ones by date and stock name and save them to parquet in terms of date/stock.

```
 stock     date     time   spread  time_diff 
  VOD      01-01    9:05    0.01     0:07     
  VOD      01-01    9:12    0.03     0:52     
  VOD      01-02   10:04    0.02     0:11
  VOD      01-02   10:15    0.01     0:10     
  VOD      01-02   10:04    0.02     0:11
  VOD      01-02   10:15    0.01     0:10    
  VOD      01-03   10:04    0.02     0:11
  VOD      01-03   10:15    0.01     0:10    
  BAT      01-01   10:25    0.03     0:39  
  BAT      01-01   11:04    0.02    22:00 
  BAT      01-02    9:04    0.02     0:05
  BAT      01-02   10:15    0.01     0:10    
  BAT      01-02   10:25    0.03     0:39  
  BAT      01-03   11:04    0.02    22:00 
  BAT      01-04    9:04    0.02     0:05
  BAT      01-04   10:15    0.01     0:10      
  BOA      01-01   10:25    0.03     0:39  
  BOA      01-01   11:04    0.02    22:00 
  BOA      01-02    9:04    0.02     0:05
  BOA      01-02   10:25    0.03     0:39  
  BOA      01-03   11:04    0.02    22:00 
  BOA      01-03    9:04    0.02     0:05
```

And save stocks from different date like

```
my_path/01-01/VOD/VOD.parquet
my_path/01-01/BAT/BAT.parquet
....
my_path/01-02/VOD/VOD.parquet
my_path/01-02/BAT/BAT.parquet
my_path/01-03/VOD/VOD.parquet
my_path/01-03/BAT/BAT.parquet
```

I know how to do this in loop

```
def split_save(df):
     spark = create_spark_session()
     
     data_list = df.select('date').distinct().unique()
     data_list = [v['date'] for v in date_list]

     stock_list = df.select('stock').distinct().unique()
     stock_list = [v['stock'] for v in stock_list ]

     for date in date_list:
          for stock in stock_list:
               stock_df = df.filter((f.col('date')==date) & (f.col('stock')==stock))
               stock_df.write.parquet(f"{my_path}/{date}/{stock}", mode='overwrite')
```

However, the process above will take 10+ hours. I want to multiprocessing for acceleration.

Any thought ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

whats the problem in using default partitionby option while writing

```
stocks_df.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("date","stock").save(f"{my_path}")
```

Comment: No problem. Thats not the question. I will be using predefined function to write parquet.

Comment: from what i see in the code you have provided you are doing exactly what a partition by does can you give an example what your code does differently from what is achieved after partitioning like above

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes partition is one of the solution here. However, its just a bit slow for me.  I tried and it will take 10+ hours. I am not sure if there is any way we can use multi threading.